# Most frequent value (mode) by group

Tags: r

I am trying to find the most frequent value by group. In the following example dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),b=c(2,2,1,2,3,3,1,1,2))  
> df  
  a b  
1 1 2  
2 1 2  
3 1 1  
4 1 2  
5 2 3  
6 2 3  
7 2 1  
8 3 1  
9 3 2
```

I would like to add a column 'c' which has the most occurring value in 'b' when its values are grouped by 'a'. I would like the following output:

```
> df  
  a b c  
1 1 2 2    
2 1 2 2    
3 1 1 2    
4 1 2 2    
5 2 3 3    
6 2 3 3    
7 2 1 3    
8 3 1 1   
9 3 2 1
```

I tried using table and tapply but didn't get it right. Is there a fast way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: This is very related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Building on Davids comments your solution is the following:

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c=Mode(b))
```

Notice though that for the tie when `df$a` is `3` then the mode for `b` is `1`.

Answer (score 8):

We could get the 'Mode' of 'b' grouped by 'a' using `ave`

```
 Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x)
 ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

df$c <-  with(df, ave(b, a, FUN=Mode))
df$c
#[1] 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c:= Mode(b), by=a][]
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun! To exclude NAs from the mode function, change the second line to 'ux <- unique(x[!is.na(x)])'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method that uses `table` to calculate a cross tab, `max.col` to find the mode per group, and `rep` together with `rle` to fill in the mode across groups.

```
# calculate a cross tab, frequencies by group
myTab <- table(df$a, df$b)
# repeat the mode for each group, as calculated by colnames(myTab)[max.col(myTab)] 
# repeating by the number of times the group ID is observed
df$c <- rep(colnames(myTab)[max.col(myTab)], rle(df$a)$length)

df
  a b c
1 1 2 2
2 1 2 2
3 1 1 2
4 1 2 2
5 2 3 3
6 2 3 3
7 2 1 3
8 3 1 2
9 3 2 2
```

Note that this assumes the data has been sorted by group. Also, the default of `max.col` is to break ties (mulitple modes) at random. If you want the first or last value to be the mode, you can set this using the ties.method argument.