# R - Fast Mode Function for use in data.table[,lapply(.SD,Mode),by=.()]

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, mode, bigdata

I'm summarizing data in a data.table, group by, where I need to take a single value of a variable in a group.  I want this value to be the mode of the group. I think it needs to be mode because usually a group is 8 rows and it will have 2 rows at one value and the other 6 or so rows will be another value.

Here's a simplified example, from this:

```
key1 2
key1 2
key1 2
key1 8
key1 2
key1 2
key1 2
key1 8
```

I want this:

```
key1 2
```

I was having trouble using the standard mode function provided by base R, so I used this solution here:
[Most frequent value (mode) by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255473/most-frequent-value-mode-by-group)

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

It worked great on my small test data set, but when I run it on my actual data set (22 million rows) it just runs and runs and runs.  All my other data.table operations that are *similar* work great and really fast, but I'm not using a UDF.  This is the structure of my data.table query:

```
ModeCharacterColumns <- ExposureHistory[,lapply(.SD,Mode), .(Key1=Key1, Key2=Key2, ..., key7=key7, key8=key8), .SDcols=('col1','col2','col3', ..., 'col53')]
```

So I'm guessing my problem is that my UDF is really slowing things down, does anyone have any suggestions where I can accomplish the same goal but get it done much quicker?

Thank you everyone!

**EDIT:**
Better representation of the data:

```
DT <- fread("key1A key2A key3A key4A 2 2 4 s
             key1A key2A key3A key4A 2 2 4 s  
             key1A key2A key3A key4A 8 8 8 t
             key1A key2A key3A key4A 2 2 4 s
             key1B key2B key3B key4B 6 6 6 v
             key1B key2B key3B key4B 2 2 5 t
             key1B key2B key3B key4B 2 2 5 v
             key1B key2B key3B key4B 2 2 5 v")
```

And the desired result:

```
result <- fread("key1A key2A key3A key4A 2 2 4 s
                 key1B key2B key3B key4B 2 2 5 v")
```

Comment: Based on this code, `,lapply(.SD,Mode), .(Key1=Key1, Key2=Key2, [...]`, your actual `data.table` seems to be much different than the example you provided. Can you include something more representative (i.e. not a two-column object, but a scaled-down version of your real data)?

Comment: Hi @nrussel, my main machine's motherboard crashed.  Just back up today.  A better data sample:
`DT <- fread("key1A key2A key3A key4A 2 2 4 s
             key1A key2A key3A key4A 2 2 4 s  
             key1A key2A key3A key4A 8 8 8 t
             key1A key2A key3A key4A 2 2 4 s
             key1B key2B key3B key4B 6 6 6 v
             key1B key2B key3B key4B 2 2 5 t
             key1B key2B key3B key4B 2 2 5 v
             key1B key2B key3B key4B 2 2 5 v")`

And this is the expected result:
`result <- fread("key1A key2A key3A key4A 2 2 4 s
                 key1B key2B key3B key4B 2 2 5 v")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using data.table to tabulate the data:

```
DT <- fread("key1 8
             key1 2
             key1 2
             key1 8
             key1 2
             key1 2
             key1 2
             key1 8")

setkeyv(
  DT[, .N, by = .(V1, V2)], #tabulate
  c("V1", "N") #sort by N
   )[, .(Mode = V2[.N]), by = V1] #most frequent value by V1
#     V1 Mode
#1: key1    2
```

You need to consider tie-breaking carefully. I might actually use a `for` loop to apply this to more value columns, but you'd need to provide a representative reproducible example if you want me to try that.

**Edit:**

Frank provides one option of doing this for several value columns in a comment:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) setDT(list(x = x))[, .N, by=x][order(-N)][1L, x]), by=V1]
```

However, I believe this copies every value column, which might slow it down too much.

Comment: For more cols `DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) setDT(list(x = x))[, .N, by=x][order(-N)][1L, x]), by=V1]`, but I don't know that this would be faster than `Mode` (as in nrussell's comment).

Comment: Thanks Roland & Frank, I will try this out, when you say mode here, are we still using the `Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}` that was above, or do I need to change that?

How do I provide a reproducible example of a data set that is 17 GB?

Comment: @Factuary Roland is just using Mode to label the output. Standard R syntax, y'know: `c(Name = Value)`. To make a reproducible example, think of data that is easily reproduce that illustrates the problem you're facing; we don't need your actual data nor necessarily all of its idiosyncracies. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/ for advice.

Comment: I added a more useful dataset and this solution works for multiple Key columns and multiple mode columns, thank you everyone!

`ModeCharacterCols2 <- setkeyv(DT[, .N, by = .(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8)], #tabulate
                              c("V1", "N") #sort by N
   )[, .(Mode = V5[.N], Mode2=V6[.N], Mode3=V7[.N], Mode4=V8[.N]), by = .(V1, V2, V3, V4)]`  Now I just need to try it on my read data set.

Comment: When I adjusted my code to your recommendations, using my posted solution on my real data set, I went from 3.5 hours of run time to 11 minutes.  Thank you very much, this is exactly what was needed!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is the function `fmode` in the *collapse* package now available on CRAN. It computes a grouped (and optionally weighted) mode in C++, the speed is very satisfying. Syntax:

```
fmode(x, g = NULL, w = NULL, ...)
```

where `x` can be a vector, matrix, data.frame or dplyr grouped tibble, `g` is a grouping vector or list of grouping vectors, and `w` is a weight vector. For mixed-type aggregations, the function `collap` provides a tidy solution. The call

```
collap(data, ~ id1 + id2, FUN = fmean, catFUN = fmode, ...)
```

aggregates the data by id1 and id2, applying the mean to all numeric columns in `data` and the mode to all non-numeric (categorical) columns in `data`. By default the data is returned with rows sorted and columns in the original order. This solution is faster than *data.table*, and the `collap` call can be futher customized.