# replace value with group's frequent value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have very basic question about replacing the values in the groups most frequent value.

Here is what I mean

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(12,12,5,13,13,5),y=c(10,22,22,22,10,22),gr=gl(2,3))
> df
   x  y gr
1 12 10  1
2 12 22  1
3  5 22  1
4 13 22  2
5 13 10  2
6  5 22  2
```

As we can see for `gr1` x column's frequent value is `12` and less frequent one is `5` and for `y` column it is `10`. I would like to replace those values with lets say `666` and `777` for x and y ,respectively. In my real data the frequent x values are always the same but less frequent ones can change so general solutions would be good. `dplyr` solution is preferable since the real data is already in the pipeline.

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
group_by(gr)%>%
....
```

the expected output

```
> df
   x  y  gr
1 12  777  1
2 12  22   1
3 666 22   1
4 13  22   2
5 13  777  2
6 666 22   2
```

Comment: We have to assume that you (at the very least) googled "most frequent value r". Please clarify why these answers weren't helpful. Cheers.

Comment: related: what have you tried

Comment: @Henrik Thanks. Yeap I searched and find this [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it is for replacing NA values and no `dplyr` solution. I also googled `replace values with most frequent values within the group` and found this [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255473/most-frequent-value-mode-by-group) and @dimitris_ps solution seems to ok.

Comment: @DanHall Sorry I could not came with any idea:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also do this with `map2` after `nest`ing.  Create a function to calculate the most frequent value ('Mode')

```
library(tidyverse)
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

After `nest`ing the variables 'x', 'y', loop through those with `map2` to replace the values that are not frequent with the corresponding replacement values i.e. 666, 777

```
df %>% 
   nest(-gr) %>% 
   mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                               map2_df(., c(666, 777), ~ 
                                replace(.x, .x != Mode(.x), .y))) ) %>% 
   unnest
#   gr   x   y
#1  1  12 777
#2  1  12  22
#3  1 666  22
#4  2  13  22
#5  2  13 777
#6  2 666  22
```

---

Or using `data.table`, it is a bit more easier.  After grouping by 'gr' in the data.table object (`setDT(df)`), use `Map` to replace the corresponding columns non-frequent values with the corresponding values of interest (666, 777)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x!= Mode(x), y), .SD, c(666, 777)), gr]
#   gr   x   y
#1:  1  12 777
#2:  1  12  22
#3:  1 666  22
#4:  2  13  22
#5:  2  13 777
#6:  2 666  22
```

Comment: Very nice `data.table` solution

Answer (score 2):

```
df2=df%>%
  group_by(gr)%>%
  mutate_all(
    funs(table(.)%>%
            which.max()%>%
             names()%>%
                as.numeric()
         )
    )

df%>%
  `is.na<-`(df2!=df)%>%
     replace_na(list(x=666,y=777))

    x   y gr
1  12 777  1
2  12  22  1
3 666  22  1
4  13  22  2
5  13 777  2
6 666  22  2
```